# How can I add chat facilities to my Drupal 6 site?

Tags: drupal, chat, chatroom

I just want to ask how one could support a chat function for Drupal 6? I created a new Drupal website and I need to add a chat functionality to it. I have, however, tried to download and enable Drupal's Chat Room module but I can't seem to make it run (or I don't know how to access it). So if it is possible, can someone please show me a tutorial on how to do this?

Sample chat application I want to put on my site is [this one](http://css-tricks.com/jquery-php-chat/).

Comment: That link has a tutorial already?

Comment: Yes it has a tutorial but it is actually a tutorial on how to make the application. I dunno how to make it run in Drupal 6 link a link for example. :D Thanks

Comment: You need to know how to link to it once you have created it from the tutorial? You can't drop an anchor into a view/template file?

Comment: Yes, but what i actually like to do is to create like a link in my drupal content page like for instance a text saying "Open Chat Room". Then on click of this link, a pop-up screen will show the chat i created using the tutorial. :)

Answer (score 0):

Install DrupalChat module - http://drupal.org/project/drupalchat.